# Adult Oriented Anime- humans at war with martian 'gods'

Tags: story-identification, anime, mars

This was set in the future where after colonizing mars humans were fighting and losing a war with an alien species that humans called 'gods'. In addition to having superior technology the so-called gods had a way of brainwashing some humans to do their bidding- one symptom of this brainwashing was a sudden onset of sex-addiction.

Answer (score 3):

I think I might have found this somewhere- an Anime titled "Big Wars" in English seems to fit the details I remember. Set in the 24th century, humans have started to colonize Mars but have met resistance from alien self-professed "gods" who claim humanity was meant to inhabit Earth and Earth alone. Part of the Gods' arsenal was a way to 'subvert' humans to serve them- those subverted often developed cases of nymphomania. The hero's superior officer became one of the subverted.